# micro service architecture database backup and restore

Tags: docker, database-design, microservices, database-backups, database-restore

I'm working on a big project, which is based on micro service architecture , so consider I have 10 service which some of them have their own database,
these databases are in different technologies (mysql, mongodb , elastic, ... )

so what is the best practice for backup and restore collection of services?

the real problem is these databases are related to each other, for example in my logic backend server I keep oauhId of each user which comes from oauth server,

now consider restore these two databases separately and now my users db in logic server contains some users which there aren't any related records to them on oauth server,

just for your information, I'm using docker , docker-compose, docker swarm for my service orchestration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an idea: check how your services depend on each other. If your dependencies are acyclic, you might be able to backup all your data outside-in or inside-out, without running into consistency issues.

Doing so would guarantee you to have no elements in services depending on an inner one after your restore.

If your services show cyclic dependencies, you might be better serviced to have each service redundantly (e.g. master slave replication). Then you can take down the slave instances, taking a backup from the whole lot of slaves while they are offline. That would allow you to create an atomic backup accross all services. However your quality of the backup is then based on the quality of your master slave replication at each service.

Lastly you could keep record of change per service, plus a full backup. Thus you can write your rollback and the start applying the record of change until you reach a consistent state accross the service instances. I think that requires you to have logical dependencies (request identifier) that allows you to correlate the record of change elements (i.e. apply them across the services without the risk to apply them in a way that defies the logical dependencies that occured when clients actually interacted with your services).

I hope these ideas can help you solve your problem :)

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by "outside-in or inside-out" ?